# How to allocate more memory to a PHP job on the iSeries?

Tags: php, db2, fastcgi, ibm-midrange

When running php scripts on the iSeries, even though I set my memory limit to -1 in php.ini... PHP says it runs out of memory around 256MB.  I'm curious if there is a way to allocate more memory to a job on the iSeries to allow PHP to allocate more memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally figured this out!

On the iSeries apache configuration you must set the following environment variable in the httpd.conf file:

```
SetEnv="LDR_CNTRL=MAXDATA=0x80000000"
```

This will allow you to access 2.25GB of memory in one php script via the web server instead of 256MB

(In my case I am using ZendServer and had to edit the config file fastcgi.conf)

Ref :

[Zend Forum Post](http://forums.zend.com/viewtopic.php?f=77&t=8404)

[IBM Reference](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/tividd/td/ITAME/GC32-0846-00/en_US/HTML/am39_perftune11.htm)